# How to concatenate previous string of an array with the next one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, but let's say there an array with these elements:

```
["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange"]
```

I would like to transfer this array into:

```
["apple", "apple/banana", "apple/banana/pear", "apple/banana/pear/kiwi", "apple/banana/pear/kiwi/orange"]
```

I need this in JavaScript and I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Please note that I'm currently working with **ES5**.

Comment: Whats wrong with pear?

Comment: Oops, I missed it. Will edit.

Comment: Downvoting because this is a question on how to elaborate an algorithm, rather than a technical difficulty with javascript.

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez I think it's a technical difficulty with Javascript as I don't know how to achieve that?

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez, the question is on topic here for Stack Overflow. However, no effort has be shown by the original poster. Voting to close.

Comment: Jeez, this is a nice and complete formatted question. Honestly in this case showing some code what he tried, will only prove that he is having troubles, but would clutter the question.

Comment: @Timmetje it is formatted but it doesn't mean it's a valid question for Stack Overflow: usually, when no effort has been made (shown) by the original poster the question would be treated as a homework question and closed.

Comment: @Ivan I know, it's just my personal opinion it will not add any value to this question. Looking at OP his profile history, I trust him he tried. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation of what you're trying to do :

**ES5**

```
var input = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange"];
var prev = '';
var output = input.map(function (el) {
  el = prev + el; prev = el + '/'; return el;
});
console.log(output);
```

**ES6**

```
let input = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange"];
let prev= '';
let output = input.map(  el => { el = prev + el; prev = el+'/'; return el})
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Quoting OP `Please note that I'm currently working with ES5.`. This is not ES5.

Comment: @Mium, after you have added a ES5 solution to your answer, your solution is better then my, because it is shorter. I vote your answer up!

Answer (score 3):

**[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is meant for these problems.**

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

And while walking through the array with `map` you can use `join()` and `slice()` to concatenate certain values from an original array.

```
let input = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange"];

let output = input.map((el, index) => { 
   return (input[index-1]) ?  input.slice(0, index+1).join('/') : el;
})
```

**output:**

> ```
> Array [
>   "apple",
>   "apple/banana",
>   "apple/banana/pear",
>   "apple/banana/pear/kiwi",
>   "apple/banana/pear/kiwi/orange"
> ]
> ```

**Some more explanation on what is happening in those 3 lines:**

```
// let's write it out.
let output = input.map((el, index) => { 
    // If there is a previous index of this array, we need to join it with this one
    if (input[index-1]) {
       // all previous values including this one
       let a = input.slice(0, index+1)
       // concatenate them all with a seperator
       let b = a.join('/');
       return b;
    } else {
       // if not just return the element
       return el;
    }
})
```

Comment: Please add some documentation for `.map` so users can better understand how to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Good idea, will do. Thanks.

Comment: Added some more explanation because that one liner might be hard to understand for new coders. And also explain `slice` and `join`.

Comment: I think you forgot to remove that one line return: `return (input[index-1]) ?  input.slice(0, index+1).join('/') : el;` ;)

Comment: What line are you talking about? ;)

Comment: Not sure... it must have vanished by now ;)

Answer (score 3):

> You wrote: *Please note that I'm currently working with ES5.*

Unfortunately, some people do not understand anymore what is ES5 and suggest ES6 solutions (with arrow function expressions, let statements and constants).

`Array.map` was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the ECMAScript 5.1 edition. It is fully supported by all modern browsers inclusive IE9.

```js
var input = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange"],
    output = input.map(function(elem, index)
    {
        return index > 0 ? input.slice(0, index + 1).join('/') : elem;
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, '\t'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = ["apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange"]
var all = [];
var str ="";
for(var i=0;i< array.length;i++)
{
   if(array[i-1]){
   str += array[i-1]+'/';
   all.push(str+array[i])
   }
   else all.push(array[i])
   
}
console.log(all);
```

Comment: check jannis code

https://jsfiddle.net/16h8mq5n/21/

fix problem :

https://jsfiddle.net/16h8mq5n/22/

Comment: Ok, I think you didn't edit it correctly then: it looked as if you had deleted all his code...

Comment: really I did not pay attention well ,thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

```
var fruits = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "banana"];
var i;
for( i=0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0){
        continue;
    }
    var temp = fruits[i];
    fruits[i] = fruits[i-1] + "/" + temp;
}
for( i=0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
    print(fruits[i]);
}
```

Here you go!

Points to remember:

- Concatenation Operator
- For loop
- continue statement
- Arrays

Answer (score 0):

### Time to `.reduce` it

This works by creating a new array, and accessing the last placed string and appending a `'/'` and then the next string `current`.

```
yourArray.reduce((newArray, current) => newArray.concat(newArray.length > 0 ? newArray[newArray.length - 1] + '/' + current : current), [])

// long version:
yourArray.reduce((newArray, current) => {
  if (newArray.length > 0) {
    return newArray.concat(current)
  } else {
    const previousString = newArray[newArray.length - 1]
    return newArray.concat(previousString + '/' + current)
  }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that do use ES6 or can transpile the code to ES5 (Using i.e: Babel)

```js
const a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
const res = a.map((_, i) => a.slice(0, i+1).join("/"));
      
console.log(res);
```